# Batch Data Entry no longer supported for Gift Entries in NPSP

Tags: batch, npsp, data-import

I am trying to insert the gift entries to salesforce in `NPSP` but recently salesforce had blocked the use of `Batch Data Entry` and it showing the page as follows.

[image]

Now sure how I am supposed to do the Gift Entry in to salesforce , is there any roadmap to it?

Comment: FYI - The best resource for the Nonprofit Success Pack NPSP is Salesforce's [Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com/publogin).  You'll find discussion groups in a wide variety of areas, and participants including other nonprofits, consultants and Salesforce.org staff.

Answer (score 0):

The path forward is described in the message displayed on this page. Some additional information is available in the [NPSP FAQ](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-FAQ#GUID-EE43841F-794B-424D-817D-895D247A5584) on the Power of Us Hub:

> As of October 1, 2020, Batch Data Entry is no longer supported. If you have any in-progress batches, you can still access those records, but you can't process them using Batch Data Entry. Contact support if you need to access in-progress batches. You may want to explore Gift Entry as an alternative to Batch Data Entry. Learn more in [Configure Gift Entry](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-Configure-Gift-Entry).

The new Gift Entry feature is the recommended route away from the deprecated Batch Data Entry feature.